# Can I use Visual Studio's testing facilities in native code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-2010

Is it possible to use Visual Studio's testing system with native code? I have no objection to recompiling the code itself under C++/CLI if it's possible the code can be recompiled without changes -- but the production code shipped has to be native code.

The Premium Edition comes with code coverage support which I might be able to get cheaply from my University -- but I can get the Professional Edition for free from DreamSpark -- and that's the only thing I can see that I'd use. (But I'd use it a LOT)

Comment: Made it CW since I don't deserve rep for a question I effectively answered myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I hate to answer my own question, [but the answer is no](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/a5edc86d-5f4d-4860-8304-674980b14254):

> This is not going to fly, you cannot use *any* unmanaged code when compiling safe.  That prevents use of *any* of the unmanaged CRT headers.

Unit testing requires /clr:safe. In other words, no, this is not supported. *sigh*